# PHPMailer hosting site using 123-reg

Tags: email, phpmailer

basically I'm hosting my site on 123-reg and have a contact form on my site which i want people to send me emails to my live.co.uk email address, i was using the basic php mail() but found all emails are constantly going into junk folder which i rather it go into inbox so was told to use phpmailer

looking into phpmailer i get to the code which asks for smtp but I'm lost with this as I'm not sure what i should be putting for the host username and password as i want the website to send emails to a given email address , any advice on what i should be putting this and why would be great

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use SMTP - you can use a local mail server and call `isMail()` instead of `isSMTP()` - though you don't even need to do that since it's the default. In the examples folder provided with PHPMailer, look at the one called `mail.phps`.